# MongoDB Query across Multiple Collections

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection (collectionA) that stores an event ID in an event array.  The event array information comes from (collectionB).
Lately when an event is deleted from CollectionB via the web app, it sometimes does not get removed from Collection A as it should.

Is there a query i can do in mongo 3.0 to check to see what event_id's exist in CollectionA that are not in collectionB.  Those will be the ones that need to be removed while the development team resolves the issue?

Comment: $lookup will perform a join operation if that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample query that will give you list of such objects, assuming, collectionA has events array with IDs from collectionB

```
db.collectionA.aggregate([
  {$unwind: '$events'},
  {$lookup: {
      from: 'collectionB',
      localField: 'events',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'event'
      }},
      {$unwind: {path: '$event', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays:true}},          
      {$match:{ 'event': {$exists:false}}},
])
```

Comment: That was what i was looking for, thank you very much!